# Generating a plot stack with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there an elegant way to append plots to a render stack/array in Shiny instead of overwriting the existing plot?  I want new plots to appear at the bottom of a page, so that the user can scroll upwards to view their previous work.  Here's a starting point:

```
require(shiny)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$execute, {
    x = sort(rnorm(input$input))
    output$plot = renderPlot( plot(x, type='l') )
  })
}

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(width=4,
  numericInput('input', 'Enter positive number and click \'Go\'. Then repeat with other numbers', value = NA, min = 1),
  actionButton('execute', 'Go')
  ),
  mainPanel( plotOutput('plot') )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will something like this do?

```
require(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(width=4,
               numericInput('input', 'Enter positive number and click \'Go\'. Then repeat with other numbers', value = 123, min = 1),
               actionButton('execute', 'Go')
  ),
  mainPanel(tags$div(id="rowLabel",mainPanel()))
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$execute, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#rowLabel",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = column(8,"Example2",plotOutput(paste0("Plot", input$execute)))

    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$execute, {
    plotname <- paste0("Plot", input$execute)
    x = sort(rnorm(input$input))
    output[[plotname]] = renderPlot( plot(x, type='l') )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thanks Pumbaa. I'm still trying to figure out what's going on with `tags$div`

Comment: U dont need 2nd one as there as there is a div to grab onto within `mainPanel`

Comment: Hmm I've hit a problem with this approach.  The plots remain live, so if you change parameters they were based on the historical plots also change. It would be preferable to simply keep the rendered images on client side and append to the DOM..

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, i thought it might relate to adding `set.seed(123)` but still cant

Comment: Thanks Porko. I'll create a reproducible example and raise a separate question :)